# Where to add external library in bonfire..?

Tags: php, bitcoin, coinbase-api

If I want to use third party/external library in code then where to add that library in bonfire.

For example : I want to add coinbase php library in mode then where I should put that library which provided in below link :

https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php

Without composer directly I want to add coinbase library into my website. anyone have idea please let me know..?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use any third party library for your project use then you have to put it libraries folder.
The path is:- application\libraries[your_libraries_folder_or_File];

Then load this library in your helper or in constructor in your controller file.

If you face any problem then please let me know.